# Set the environment variable in /etc/environment via terminal on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, sudo, ubuntu-20.04

[image: Command used :]

I want to set environment variable via terminal in /etc/environment file only, not in .bashrc or other files.But, its throwing permission denied error. how to achieve this?

Comment: Check in selinux or apparmor is stopping the write.

Answer (score -1):

Well here is the command

sudo echo "JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"" >> sudo /etc/environment